# capture vsim exit code or current simulator state with script

Tags: tcl, modelsim

I'm trying to write a Tcl script which loads a simulation in ModelSim and then does some other stuff, so it needs to determine if the simulation loaded successfully or not. But the `vsim` command does not seem to return any value, at least that I can figure out how to capture. As a test, I did:

```
set rv [vsim $sim_name]
```

`$rv` is always empty, regardless of whether the sim loaded or not, so using `catch` doesn't work. My current workaround is to try something after loading that only works in a simulation context and that *does* return a value, and catch that instead. For example:

```
vsim $sim_name
if {[catch {log *} ...
```

But that's far from ideal. Is there a better way to detect whether or not `vsim` ran successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling elaboration errors at the startup of simulations you can associate a callback using the `onElabError` command. Your callback can set a global variable that you examine later:

```
onElabError {global vsim_init_failure; set vsim_init_failure 1}
...
set vsim_init_failure 0
vsim $sim_name
if {$vsim_init_failure} ...
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I'm looking for, though I'm still surprised vsim doesn't return any value.

Comment: As a further elaboration you could encapsulate this in a wrapper around the vsim command that returns a status code or throws an exception as desired.